# ffmpeg HEVC with HLS specific fragment duration

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265, hls

I use a 10bit build of ffmpeg/x265 to run the following command where I decode an input x265/10bit video, pipe it into another cmd line tools and pipe again the output into a new ffmpeg instance where I want to re-encode and fragment with a 3second fragment duration. Note that the same line worked as expected with x264/8bit encoding.

```
ffmpeg-hi10-heaac -y -an -i "./HEVC.mp4" -s 3840x2160 -f rawvideo - | myCLI | ffmpeg-hi10-heaac -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -s 3840x2160 -r 23.976 -i - -c:v libx265 -b:v 5000K -g 24 -keyint_min 24 -sc_threshold 0 -map 0:v -f stream_segment -segment_time 3 -segment_list manifest.m3u8 -segment_list_type m3u8 output.%05d.ts
```

The problem is that:

- manifest say that the fragment duration are around 10seconds
- and it's true each .ts at the output is around 10seconds long.

I would like to know if it's a known issue, if there is a work-around or if it's coming from the option I used or a combinaison of those options ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must also set the gop size. -g [fps * segment time]

Comment: Yes I had only 1 I-frame, but it looks Luke the 'g' option is not the one to use, I have to set the ' x265-params' min-keyint etc... Like some ffmpeg option weren't translate into x265 option ! And even with that change, the segment length is still 10 seconds.